# How can I merge text with different color formatting into one cell and keep the color formatting?

Tags: excel, vba

**Data:**

I have the following table:

```
160  89  85 116 161
147 117 133 148 191
 93  91  94  92 107
147 148 177 133 205
116 147 117 190 148
```

**Problem:**

I want to merge the data into a single column.

The code for a single row, run through a button.

**Code:**

```
Sub mergeStuff()
    Range("M3").Value = CStr(Range("H3").Value) + "," + CStr(Range("I3").Value) + "," + CStr(Range("J3").Value) + "," + CStr(Range("K3").Value) + "," + CStr(Range("L3").Value)
End Sub
```

**Output example:**

```
    160,89,85,116,161
    147,117,133,148,191
     93,91,94,92,107
    147,148,177,133,205
    116,147,117,190,148
```

**Question:**

The numbers are formatted. They have different colors. How can I merge in one cell and keep the color formatting?

Comment: make a temp variable to store the color of each cell that you will be concatenating and then color it after concatenation

Comment: So you're suggesting that I should for example save the five color values and somehow add them latter after I concatenated the string values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will store the color values, concatenate the cells, and then color the strings based on the stored color values.  The `1 to 5` should be changed to reflect the number of columns that you are concatenating.  In your example, there are 5 columns.  The `1 to 3` portion can be left alone.

```
Sub mergeStuff()

    Dim arrColors(1 To 5, 1 To 3) As Long
    Dim rIndex As Long
    Dim cIndex As Long
    Dim StartColor As Long
    Dim strOutput As String
    Dim i As Long

    For rIndex = 3 To Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
        StartColor = 1
        strOutput = vbNullString
        For cIndex = Columns("H").Column To Columns("L").Column
            strOutput = strOutput & "," & Cells(rIndex, cIndex).Value
            arrColors(cIndex - Columns("H").Column + 1, 1) = StartColor
            arrColors(cIndex - Columns("H").Column + 1, 2) = Len(Cells(rIndex, cIndex).Value)
            arrColors(cIndex - Columns("H").Column + 1, 3) = Cells(rIndex, cIndex).Font.Color
            StartColor = StartColor + Len(Cells(rIndex, cIndex).Value) + 1
        Next cIndex

        With Cells(rIndex, "M")
            .Value = Mid(strOutput, 2) 'Remove beginning comma
            For i = 1 To UBound(arrColors, 1)
                .Characters(arrColors(i, 1), arrColors(i, 2)).Font.Color = arrColors(i, 3)
            Next i
        End With
    Next rIndex

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried out this code. Its definitely the best answer yet although some time i does not color as it should. Some times the values are or one color or the other one. Do you have any idea why is this happening?

Comment: I would have to see some example data where the code is not working properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .Characters method to format characters within a cell, or within a string value of a cell.

An example would be:

```
Cells(1, 1).Characters(1, 3).Font.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
```

Comment: That was the answer I was searching for.